# How can I debug JS code in CSSEdit?

Tags: javascript, debugging, client-side, cssedit

Yeah, sounds silly but I'm a designers and the site I'm working on is not working in CSSEdit. Which is bad for me, very bad. The site has a massive JS/Ajax client and works in all browsers, IE, Firefox and Safari that uses the same browser engine as CSSEdit!

Since MacRabbit has no customer service (they don't really answer email) this is a last resort.

Any tips would be greatly valued. Thx.

Comment: Does MacRabbit have a support forum? The internets does not seem to know about it,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable the WebKit Inspector (which includes some tools for debugging Javascript) by quitting CSSEdit, running the following command in the Terminal, and then restarting CSSEdit:

```
defaults write com.macrabbit.CSSEdit WebKitDeveloperExtras -bool YES
```

To open the WebKit Inspector, right click in a preview window and choose "Inspect Element".

**Original post:**

Your best bet (if you can't get ahold of MacRabbit support) is likely going to be finding an alternate workflow.  Although CSSEdit's override feature is a vast boon, it's certainly possible to develop CSS for an existing site using Firefox with [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) and the [Web Developer extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60).

If you have access to a testing server (not the live environment) via FTP, you could also remotely edit the stylesheet using CSSEdit, and preview your changes in another browser (all Mac FTP programs that I know of offer an "Edit with..." option for remote files).

Good luck!

Comment: Thx for the answer, after digging our way through the code using returns and writing inside the page with .innerHTML (alerts don't work in CSSEdit) the bug was in a browser check script, totally our own fault.